# Is it possible to write a SafeNavigation operator in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, operators

As I was reading an article about the [SafeNavigator operator introduction in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator.aspx)

I'm wondering if is it possible using C++ to write that kind of operator ? for example to simply write :

```
auto a = node->child()->child();
if( a != nullptr)
{ ... }
```

instead of something like:

```
if( node != nullptr && node->child() != nullptr && (auto a = node->child()->child()) != nullptr)
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two ways of doing this:

1) First the "non-standard behaviour that will ***most likely*** work in reality" by checking for a call on a null instance:

> ```
> class   node
> {
> public:
>   node()
>     :
>     child_(nullptr)
>   {
>   }
>
>   ...
>
>   node* child()
>   {
>     if (this == nullptr)
>       {
>         return nullptr;
>       }
>     return child_;
>   }
>
>   ...
>
> private:
>   node  *child_;
> };
> ```

2) Second, a "standard friendly way" by using nearly the same principle applying the [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern):

> ```
> class   node
> {
> public:
>   node()
>     :
>     is_null_(false),
>     child_(nullptr)
>   {
>   }
>
>   node(nullptr_t)
>     :
>     is_null_(true),
>     child_(nullptr)
>   {
>   }
>
>
>   ...
>
>   node* child()
>   {
>     if ((is_null_) || (child_ == nullptr))
>       {
>         return new node(nullptr);;
>       }
>     return child_;
>   }
>
>   bool  operator!=(nullptr_t)
>   {
>      return (!is_null_);
>   }
>
>   bool  operator==(nullptr_t)
>   {
>      return (is_null_);
>   }
>
>
>   ...
>
> private:
>   bool  is_null_;
>   node  *child_;
> };
> ```

Comment: Really nice, I will keep that design I mind, Thanks!